# Magento 2.2.6: Programmatically unchecking "My billing and shipping address are the same"

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to programmatically uncheck the "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox in Magento 2.2.6 checkout when a button is pressed.

**Background:**

I have built a button and some js into my template for simple "in-store pickup" option. It automatically adds the store address to the shipping address and selects the "In Store Pickup" shipping method.

I am using this jquery code in the extensions onepage.phtml file and it works fine, but I just can't figure out the last step to uncheck that button.

```
        $(document).on('click', '#in-store-pickup', function() {    
            // Set Shipping Address     
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='firstname']").val( "In-Store" ).change();
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='lastname']").val( "Pickup" ).change();
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='city']").val( "<?php echo $city; ?>" ).change();
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='region_id']").val( "<?php echo $regionId; ?>" ).change();  
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='postcode']").val( "<?php echo $postcode; ?>" ).change();   
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='telephone']").val( "<?php echo $phone; ?>" ).change(); 
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='company']").val( "<?php echo $name; ?>" ).change();
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='street\\[0\\]']").val( "<?php echo $street1; ?>" ).change();
            $('.shipping-address-box').find("input[name='street\\[1\\]']").val( "<?php echo $street2; ?>" ).change();

            // Set payment method
            $('#s_method_amstrates_amstrates8').trigger('click');

            // Need to uncheck the "My billing and shipping address are the same"


        });
```

(For the record, I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing above as well)

I have tried several things including triggering a change on the checkbox, but I believe the knockout bindings interfere with it. Thanks